# Powershell Get-PnpDevice fails

Tags: powershell

When running this PS command as an administrator, I get an error I can't figure out.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-pnpdevice -status UNKNOWN -class 'Monitor' | disable-pnpdevice

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Disable" on target "Win32_PnPEntity: Generic PnP Monitor (DeviceID = "DISPLAY\NEC6865\4&1919A1B7&0&UID224795")".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y
disable-pnpdevice : Generic failure
At line:1 char:50
+ get-pnpdevice -status UNKNOWN -class 'Monitor' | disable-pnpdevice
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Win32_PnPEntity...7&0&UID224795"):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice
```

Comment: Are you running the command elevated?

Comment: I opened Powershell as an admin if that's what you mean. I'm fairly new to PS.

Comment: confirm is usually used to (Prompts you for confirmation before executing the command) . Have you left -confirm off? Or possibly used the -force instead of confirm. This post may help you understand what they do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6

Comment: -Force returns "A parameter cannot be found" error. Running it with -Confirm only prompts for confirmation (as the documentation says it will), and running it without -Confirm also prompts.

Comment: I updated the question with my full input and output and ignored the need to run this without any user interaction. It still fails.